# list iterator error c++

Tags: c++, list, iterator

I have the following code : im not sure what the issue is. It is underlining the ' <<' after the cout in the for loop.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <ostream>
#include <istream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include <iterator>
#include <list>

list<weatherStation> station;
weatherStation *aStation;

aStation = new weatherStation();

for (list<weatherStation>::iterator it = station.begin(); it != station.end(); ++it)
        {
            cout << *it << endl;
        }
```

The errors i'm getting are:

> Error 2   error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a
>   right-hand operand of type 'weatherStation' (or there is no acceptable
>   conversion)   \zorak2\users$\s0941625\my documents\visual studio
>   2013\projects\lentzis\lentzis\newmain.cpp 100 1   Project1

and

> 3 IntelliSense: no operator "<<" matches these operands
>                   operand types are: std::ostream << weatherStation \zorak2\users$\s0941625\My Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\lentzis\lentzis\newMain.cpp 101 10  Project1

Comment: im not sure what you mean by defined?

Comment: Since there is no definition whatsoever of `weatherStation` it's surprising that the compiler didn't start complaining much sooner.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**

```
weatherStation
```

needs to be display-able by `std::cout`. One option is to define the corresponding stream operator as a `friend` inside your class:

```
inline friend 
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const weatherStation& ws)
{
    os << weatherStation.some_member; // you output it
    return os;
}
```

**Long answer**

The display issue is a recurring problem in C++. What you can do in the future is define an abstract class, we'll call it `IDisplay`, which declares a pure virtual function `std::ostream& display(std::ostream&) const` and declares `operator<<` as a friend. Then every class that you want to be display-able must inherit from `IDisplay` and consequently implement the `display` member function. This approach reuses the code and is pretty elegant. Example below:

```
#include <iostream>

class IDisplay
{
private:
    /**
    * \brief Must be overridden by all derived classes
    *
    * The actual stream extraction processing is performed by the overriden
    * member function in the derived class. This function is automatically
    * invoked by friend inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,
    * const IDisplay& rhs).
    */
    virtual std::ostream& display(std::ostream& os) const = 0;

public:
    /**
    * \brief Default virtual destructor
    */
    virtual ~IDisplay() = default;

    /**
    * \brief Overloads the extraction operator
    *
    * Delegates the work to the virtual function IDisplay::display()
    */
    friend inline
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const IDisplay& rhs)
    {
        return rhs.display(os);
    }
}; /* class IDisplay */

class Foo: public IDisplay
{
public:
    std::ostream& display(std::ostream& os) const override 
    {
        return os << "Foo";
    }
};

class Bar: public IDisplay
{
public:
    std::ostream& display(std::ostream& os) const override 
    {
        return os << "Bar";
    }
};

int main() 
{
    Foo foo;
    Bar bar;
    std::cout << foo << " " << bar;    
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/21c980a12426aa91)